# Selenium python click on span class

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, intranet

I am trying to automate intranet site. The source code is bunch of tables and consists of hundreds of codes like below:

```
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_lblCaseType"></span>
</td><td nowrap="nowrap">
<span class="fakeLink" title="Edit case" onmouseenter="this.focus()" onclick="editCase('286658')"> 286658</span>
</td><td nowrap="nowrap">1360428-0000</td><td align="center" style="color:Red;">
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label2">13,0</span>
</td><td align="center">
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label2">8,8</span>
</td><td align="center">
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label9">R</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label6">Waiting for info fr. suppl.</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label11" title="1360428-0000 Condensate Cup&lt;br/>Price is missing, please update price&lt;br/>(enquiry by Name 11/1)" class="vtip">1360428-0000 Co</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label12" title="Please source" class="vtip">Please source</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label7">Fname Lname</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label1"></span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label8">Price or delivery time missing</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label3">A21</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label10">TS6</span>
</td><td>
<span id="GridView1_ctl51_Label5">FName Lname</span>
</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
```

I need to capture part number 1360428-0000 and click "editCase (286658)". I have two problems:

1. Use part number 1360428-0000 as reference to find case number 286658
2. Imitate click on 286658 with xpath? Couldn't make it work.

I tried to figure out problem #2 using below code with no success:

```
def IeTest():
    driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Python34\\IEDriverServer.exe")
    driver.get("http://intranet.company.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(driver.title)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@onclick,"286658")]')
    elem.click()
IeTest()
```

Any help is appreciated. I also must use IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath to find the target `span` by part number `"1360428-0000"` :

```
//td[text()='1360428-0000']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/span[@title='Edit case']
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/29293a85ff0693f008ce3c58ca971411)</kbd>**

Comment: Is [1] really needed at the end ?

Comment: @Newcomer not really, since there is only one `span` in the `td`. I rather meant it after `td`, as in the updated XPath

Comment: Solution checks out for source snippet, but not for full source. I am no programmer/webdesigner, but I think code I am dealing with is from hell. It's one big frame with all information about each part (10k+ code). I uploaded bigger snippet to give better idea what it is: Source code(http://textuploader.com/57o57)

Comment: Ok, I was going nuts why no elements were found apart html and it turns out the frame has different url link, so i have been scrapping wrong source code. I used your solution and it worked. Thank you so much! If it's not too much asking, can you help me understand logic behind `/preceding-sibling::td[1]/`?

Comment: Preceding-sibling returns elements, located before the context element at the same level (hence *siblings*). Index 1 means to return only the one nearest preceding sibling